# How can I pass http header from JQuery to Rails via get request?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4, http-headers

I would like to pass header from jQuery `ajax` method to Rails. This is my request:

`$.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/examples", method: "GET", beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('AuthenticationKey', 'some_key');}, dataType: "json" })`

And here is routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :v1, defaults: { format: :json } do
    devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "v1/sessions", registrations: "v1/registrations" }
    get 'examples', to:'examples#index'
  end
end
```

This `get` route for examples works if there is no header, but when I set custom header it doesn't.

```
Started OPTIONS "/v1/examples" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-10 18:52:47 +0200
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/v1/examples"):
```

How can I pass this header to my application?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://localhost:3000/v1/examples", 
    headers: {'AuthenticationKey': 'some_key'},
    dataType: "json"
})
```

(default method is 'GET')

Use the `beforeSend` function only if you want to change the default value for the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, which is always sent.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I tried this at the beginning, but it doesn't work as well.